# How to translate ruby regex to javascript regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, ruby

Im using validates_format_of method to check a input text
Javascript cant read this regex. How or where I can change this regex to be as original:

```
(?<=^|,|\b)[1-7](?=$|,|\b)
```

Thanks

UPDATE:
the input text must be one o more digits separated by comma, ex: 1|1,2|1,2,3

Comment: The regex seems to be valid for JavaScript either. Could you provide an example of which text is supposed to be valid, and which is not?

Comment: The `/\b[1-7]\b/` should do, because `\b` is more generic than `,` and `^`/`$`.

Comment: `\b` covers all cases of `^` or `,`  behind and `$` or `,` ahead. So, use `/\b[1-7]\b/` However, it is equivalent  to this as well `(?:^|,|\b)[1-7](?=$|,|\b)` which is _verbose_ and overstated in the form of `^$` and `,`

Comment: Positive lookbehind is not supported in Mozila and some other browsers too, so you need that to change to normal regex

Comment: the text must be one o more digits separated by comma, ex: 1|1,2|1,2,3

Comment: Ok, try `/(?:^|,)[1-7](?:,|$)/`, why use `\b`? If you are checking against a string, why use lookarounds?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @wiktor said you should use

```
\b[1-7]\b
```

As \b only asserts positions, you don't need to worry about matching more than [1-7].

@Code Maniac correctly stated that look behind is not supported in Mozilla and many others, so about it. [see](https://caniuse.com/#search=regular)